# Update error "apt-get update"

Tags: updates, apt

When I update to "sudo apt-get update" appears this errors into terminal. How can I solved it? Thanks!

```
(...)
Err:6 https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb <channel>/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
(...)
W: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb <channel> Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: No s'ha pogut obtenir https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb/dists/<channel>/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Alguns índex no s'han pogut baixar. S'han descartat, o en el seu lloc s'han emprat els antics.
```

Answer (score 1):

after googling your repository i deduced that you want to install facebook messenger desktop :)

so follow these instructions as said on github

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 6DDA23616E3FE905FFDA152AE61DA9241537994D
```

2nd step, he said replace  with **stable**, **beta** or **dev** so result can be (the recommended one is stable but you can also try the dev or beta one and you can uninstall it if it has a problem :

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb/ stable main" |
  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aluxian.list
```

or

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb/ beta main" |
  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aluxian.list
```

or

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb/ dev main" |
  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aluxian.list
```

after that:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install messengerfordesktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the repository source with 404 error code,
In case you would like to automate the same,

Go [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/432364)

Once the ppa's that are not found are removed apt-get update will work just fine.